# What informations can PHP collectes about visitors?

Tags: php, server, analytics

I'm trying to make a web analytics using php **only**, I know php is a server side language so the information collected will be very limited.

There are some predefined variables to get details about visitors such as:

```
IP : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
Browser : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
Referrer : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Is there other php codes that can provide more details about a visitor ?

Comment: The headers depends on what the browser sends.  Just dump $_SERVER

Comment: PHP can show any information that the client sends to the server. You can find all of the data inside the `$_SERVER` variable. Just print it (`var_dump($_SERVER);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user the information contained in the super global $SERVER:

```
<?php 
 $indicesServer = array('PHP_SELF', 
'argv', 
'argc', 
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 
'SERVER_ADDR', 
'SERVER_NAME', 
'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 
'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 
'REQUEST_METHOD', 
'REQUEST_TIME', 
'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT', 
'QUERY_STRING', 
'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 
'HTTP_CONNECTION', 
'HTTP_HOST', 
'HTTP_REFERER', 
'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 
'HTTPS', 
'REMOTE_ADDR', 
'REMOTE_HOST', 
'REMOTE_PORT', 
'REMOTE_USER', 
'REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER', 
'SCRIPT_FILENAME', 
'SERVER_ADMIN', 
'SERVER_PORT', 
'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 
'PATH_TRANSLATED', 
'SCRIPT_NAME', 
'REQUEST_URI', 
'PHP_AUTH_DIGEST', 
'PHP_AUTH_USER', 
'PHP_AUTH_PW', 
'AUTH_TYPE', 
'PATH_INFO', 
'ORIG_PATH_INFO') ; 

echo '<table cellpadding="10">' ; 
foreach ($indicesServer as $arg) { 
    if (isset($_SERVER[$arg])) { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>' . $_SERVER[$arg] . '</td></tr>' ; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$arg.'</td><td>-</td></tr>' ; 
    } 
} 
echo '</table>' ;
```

for more info you can go to:
http://php.net/reserved.variables.server